# Polymer posts [object Object] instead of a body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, polymer

I'm new to Polymer and I wanted to text AJAX post. However, instead of body that I've declared it posts `[object Object]` with content type `text/plain`. There's nothing wrong with the server configuration, I've tested it with rest client, controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stringCount", method = RequestMethod.POST,    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<StringUtilsModel> count(@RequestBody StringUtilsModel string) {
    System.out.println("here");
    System.out.println(string.getStringInput());
    return new ResponseEntity<StringUtilsModel>(string, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The polymer ajax I make with iron-ajax which looks like this:

```
 <iron-ajax method="POST"
                       contentType="application/json"
                       auto url="/stringCount"
                       body='{"stringInput":"sum String"}'
                       handle-as="json"
                       on-response="responseHandler">
            </iron-ajax>
```

I use latest Firefox (41.0) also tested on old IE 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentType` attribute should be written as `content-type`.

Comment: Indeed, i was mislead by the name of property name on doc page https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax, thought that since it's in camelCase it is valid.

Comment: @ZZ5 `camelCased` properties are converted to `dashed-attributes` in Polymer. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping

Answer (score 1):

I think you have structured your code correctly.

Try `JSON.stringify()` to view your `body`.